# MongoDb, query the last, and group by

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I m actually having trouble when dealing with MongoDb.

I need to :

- get all of the last entries
- concerning a field
- like : SELECT MAX(id), foreignKey FROM t_table GROUP BY foreignKey

I know that we can use $last with mongodb, but I dont know at all how to proceed.

I tried :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$zone._id",
           lastRegistered: { $last: "$_id" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

But it does'nt seems to give me what I need

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLE**

According to this three:

```
  { _id: 55d5a01f9f58d2cc0eb79f5d,
    controlDate: Thu Aug 20 2015 11:38:40 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)),
    zone:
     { _id: 55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c266,
       zoneName: 'Syphon 1',
     },
    actif: true 
    },



  { _id: 55d59f129f58d2cc0eb79f5c,
    controlDate: Fri Aug 21 2015 07:34:12 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)),
    zone:
     { _id: 55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c266,
       zoneName: 'Syphon 1',
     },
    actif: true 
    }



  { _id: 55d5a01f9f58d2cc0eb79f5e,
        controlDate: Fri Aug 20 2015 08:38:40 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)),
        zone:
         { _id: 55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c278,
           zoneName: 'Other zone',
         },
        actif: true 
        },
```

I need to get :

```
  { _id: 55d59f129f58d2cc0eb79f5c,
    controlDate: Fri Aug 21 2015 07:34:12 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)),
    zone:
     { _id: 55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c266,
       zoneName: 'Syphon 1',
     },
    actif: true 
    }



  { _id: 55d5a01f9f58d2cc0eb79f5e,
        controlDate: Fri Aug 20 2015 08:38:40 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)),
        zone:
         { _id: 55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c278,
           zoneName: 'Other zone',
         },
        actif: true 
        },
```

Which means : I need to get the last (by id or date, never mind) of this collection grouped by the Zone _id. (2 lines, because I have 2 dataset for ONE zone (I need only the last) and I need the last of the other zone (only 1 line so..))

Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: The code example does not seem to match the document examples. You are referring to a field `$foreignField` which doesn't exist in your documents. Also, you are grouping by `_id`, which doesn't make much sense because `_id` is always unique (unless you do an `$unwind` aggregation step before). Maybe you mean to group by `zone._id`?

Comment: That was for an example. i m going to modify it to match with the real context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always use [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) to return the whole document on the grouping boundary:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$zone._id",
        "doc": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
    }}
 ])
```

Or with direct sort control rather than the natural order:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$zone._id",
        "doc": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
    }}
  ])
```

But note that the `$group` pipeline does not guarantee a retained document order, so if you need that then you `$sort` again:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$zone._id",
        "doc": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "doc._id": 1 } }
 ])
```

In all cases the alterate to `$$ROOT` is simply to declare [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) explicitly for each field you want from the document. By contrast the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator applies only to the specified field, so this is generally not of use to you when you want documents from the grouping boundary as `$last` does.

---

Considering the "last" example there and also removing the appropriate data from your examples then I get:

```js
{
    "_id" : "55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c266",
    "doc" : {
            "_id" : "55d5a01f9f58d2cc0eb79f5d",
            "zone" : {
                    "_id" : "55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c266",
                    "zoneName" : "Syphon 1"
            },
            "actif" : true
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c278",
    "doc" : {
            "_id" : "55d5a01f9f58d2cc0eb79f5e",
            "zone" : {
                    "_id" : "55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c278",
                    "zoneName" : "Other zone"
            },
            "actif" : true
    }
}
```

Altered input is this:

```js
{
    "_id" : "55d5a01f9f58d2cc0eb79f5d",
    "zone" : {
            "_id" : "55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c266",
            "zoneName" : "Syphon 1"
    },
    "actif" : true
},
{
    "_id" : "55d59f129f58d2cc0eb79f5c",
    "zone" : {
            "_id" : "55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c266",
            "zoneName" : "Syphon 1"
    },
    "actif" : true
},
{
    "_id" : "55d5a01f9f58d2cc0eb79f5e",
    "zone" : {
            "_id" : "55cb5bb42d191d2022c5c278",
            "zoneName" : "Other zone"
    },
    "actif" : true
}
```

Not bothering with correct `ObjectId` values in case as the hex string values are lexical just as the internal sort of an `ObjectId` would be anyway.

Which are the "last" documents for each provided `zone._id` value from the collection, ordered by the original document `_id` value given.

Comment: I tried this one, but the result set is only one line, instead of two in my case

Comment: @Skahrz Not possible on the data you posted. You have "two" distinct values of `zone._id` and therefore you get two results. That is what `$group` does. Do I really need to post "my" results out of the three items you posted? Or can you actually do this yourself? I suspect you are abstracting your "real" code and data and applying what I have taought you here incorrectly in your "real" code.

Comment: @Skahrz So I have provided the output from the aggregation pipeline as used exactly as presented and also the input documents ( mirrored from your own example ) that are used as the source to produce the result, I would think that not only is the answer "explanatory" and with working examples, that also consider that there is only one other attempt at an answer ( strangely upvoted though completely syntactically incorrect, and I don't mean just typing errors ) that cannot solve the problem. As the results I show, clearly have. I hope that was not your upvote there BTW.

Answer (score 5):

`$last` gives you the value of the last document which is processed by your grouping. You can not predict the order in which documents are processed, unless you sort the documents. So you don't get the results you expect.

Try adding a $sort stage before your $group stage to get the documents in ascending date order:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: {
           "control_date":1
       }
     },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$zone._id",
           lastRegistered: { $last: "$_id" },
           zoneName:"$zone.zoneName",
           control_id:"$_id",
           actif:"$actif",
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: I tried this one, but the result set is only one line, instead of two in my case

Comment: @Skahrz Please double-check that the `zone._id` values of the documents are indeed distinct.

Comment: I think the main problems here are that the other fields such as "control_id", "actif" lack the `$last` or any other grouping accumulator. Therefore making the entire statement invalid. And after a couple of edit revisions even.