# MongoDB aggregation on same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to get the value from another document and here are my sample documents :

```
[
  {
    "product_code": "0172745",
    "condition_type": "ZPRE",
    "price_group": "33",
    "visibility": "brp, network",
    "sales_org": "1010",
    "distr_channel": "10",
    "price_type": "dealer",
    "price_market": "na",
    "valid_from": "2019-07-01",
    "valid_to": "9999-12-31",
    "price_price_uom": "5.30",
    "price_uom": "PC",
    "price_sales_uom": "12.90",
    "sales_uom": "PC",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "last_change_date": "2020-01-17T20:14:15"
    }
  },
  {
    "product_code": "0172745",
    "condition_type": "ZPBA",
    "price_group": "2R",
    "visibility": "brp, network",
    "sales_org": "1010",
    "distr_channel": "10",
    "price_type": "dealer",
    "price_market": "na",
    "valid_from": "2019-07-01",
    "valid_to": "9999-12-31",
    "price_price_uom": "5.30",
    "price_uom": "PC",
    "price_sales_uom": "5.300",
    "sales_uom": "PC",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "last_change_date": "2020-01-17T20:14:15"
  }
]
```

Output should be `document 2` + `price_sales_uom` from `document 1`, aggregation is `product_code` and `condition_type`:

```
 {
    "product_code": "0172745",
    "condition_type": "ZPBA",
    "price_group": "2R",
    "price_sales_uom": "12.90"

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `aggregation is product_code and condition_type` ? Also on what basis you need `price_sales_uom` & `price_group` ? You question is so confusing !! Also is `price_sales_uom` a type of String ? Please try answer below & let us know..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb, query the last, and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133867/mongodb-query-the-last-and-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query, this will group all documents based on `product_code` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$product_code', product_code: { $first: '$product_code' },
            condition_type: { $last: '$condition_type' },
            price_group: { $last: '$price_group' },
            price_sales_uom: { $max: '$price_sales_uom' }
        }
    }, { $project: { _id: 0 } }])
```

**Note :** At it's given state of this question, this query assumes to get maximum value for `price_sales_uom` over matched documents (If it has to be from first document use `$first`), Similarly `condition_type`, `price_group` are being retrieved from last document in the group, but for `product_code` really doesn't matter whether `$first` or `$last` as they'll are same.