# Mongoose group documents by value but only return latest document each

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called "Words", where I save different Words in different languages. Words are stored in "content" and their language code in "lang" (en, de, fr).

This is my Words schema:

```
content: { 
  type: String
},
lang: {
  type: String,
  enum: ['en', 'de', 'fr']
}
```

I am now trying to retrieve the **latest** stored value for each language, only returning one document each.

This is my desired example output:

```
[{
  lang: "en",
  content: "Whats up"
},{
  lang: "de",
  content: "Guten Tag"
},{
  lang: "fr",
  content: "Salut"
}]
```

I've already tried to use aggregate function with group. But now the two letter language code gets returned as the document id:

```
Words.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: '$lang'
  }
}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb, query the last, and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133867/mongodb-query-the-last-and-group-by) As given the this link, you need to use `$last` & `$$ROOT` to get the last doc out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Words.aggregate([{$sort: {'_id': -1}}, 
{$group: {_id:'$lang',
  word: {
    $push: {
      _id: '$_id',
      content: '$content'
    }
  }
}}, 
{$project: {
  _id:0,
  lang:'$_id',
  content: {$arrayElemAt:['$word.content',0]}
}}])
```

First, I used sort on _id by descending order. (Assuming you had use mongoDB auto-generated _id)

Next, group all the content by language and lastly project the first content which is the latest according to _id.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Cheers and thank you!

Comment: Wow. It helped me a lot! Thanks!