# mongodb multiple find by multiple conditions and one result nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a collection for users transactions. i want to use a query by three id of users to get last transaction for each one. and i don't want to use a loop to do a query per user.
i used this:

```
const items = await db
      .collection("transactions")
      .find({ user: users[1] , user: users[2], user: users[3] })
      .limit(3)
      .sort({ $natural: -1 })
      .toArray();
```

but it doesn't contain one result per condition because i know i'm doing it wrong.
i use:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

how should i do that?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do an aggregation using `$group` and `$last`.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#examples

```js
db.collection("transactions").aggregate( [
  {
    $group: {
       _id: user,
       txnId: { $last: "$_id" }
    }
  }
] ).toArray();
```

This answer might also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32134655/1742298